# rewrite rule for domain / subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My hosting company provided me with a rewrite rule to redirect all traffic to https witch works as expected.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

FallbackResource /index.php
```

My subdomain application (subdomain.example.com) points to the same physical directory as example.com and the application serves different applications according to where the request came from.

With this rewrite rule a request to subdomain.example.com gets rewritten to example.com

How would a rule have to look like so that all domains are rewritten independently? The fallback to index.php must also work for all domains.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=304,L,QSA]

FallbackResource /index.php
```

Edit 1: hold on a sec, editing this as there is an error with it

Edit 2: done. It should work now

Edit 3: Edited again. Found out that "CACHE_URL" isn't a server variable in Apache

Comment: I am sorry to say that I still have no luck with this rule. It is not rewriting to https.

Comment: in fact I don't have access to the pages anymore

Comment: @Delcon strange, I tested this myself and it was rerouting to https just fine. What do you mean you don't have access to the pages anymore?

Comment: only if I open up a new page and try to access - nothing is displayed. it just dies silently. If I go back to my old rule it works again

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

FallbackResource /index.php
```